# Measuring amount of light using OpenCV?

Tags: c, opencv

My idea is to use vision sensor (camera) to measure amount of light. I would
like to know is it possible to acquire information about light intensity using
OpenCV?
Is there some openCV function property which can get such information from the
scene?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Light intensity is a tough one because most color systems can't tell the difference between lightness of a color and light intensity. You can get some idea of the light intensity in a scene by measuring the "lightness" of the scene overall. The saturation might also give you a decent clue.

To do this I would convert the color space to HSL and then aggregate the L channel to get a very rough measure of Lightness. The S channel is the Saturation.

OpenCV has this [natively](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=hls#cv-cvtcolor)* but it's not a difficult operation. The Wikipedia page has the formulas.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

*Thanks jlengrand and Seçkin Savaşçı

Comment: OpenCV definitely does has this. Let me search for it

Comment: @jlengrand I found it for you: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=hls#cv-cvtcolor